# Typescript argument of function as interface or type

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback

Is it possible to use the argument of a function definition in an interface as type

( into an array of type or interface ? )

```
export interface MiddlewareEvent {
    onNewAccount: (accountId: string, timestamp: number) => void,
    onAccountDelete: (accountId:string, timestamp:number)=>void,
}

 const middlewareMap: Map<keyof MiddlewareEvent,((...arg: any) => void )[]> = new Map();

function fireMiddleware<EventName extends keyof MiddlewareEvent>(
    eventId: EventName,
    args: any[]
) {
    const middleware = middlewareMap.get(eventId);
    if (middleware?.length) {
         middleware.forEach((m) => {
                 m(...args);
        });     
    }
}

fireMiddleware(`onNewAccount`, [123, `2020-05-21T21:42:00.496Z`])
console.log(`Wait, Typescript should have prevented this`)
console.log(`account Id is string not number`)
console.log(`datetime has been changed to timestamp and is now a number`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Parameters` type returns the arguments of a function as a tuple.

```
type A = Parameters<(a: string, b: number) => void> // [string, number]
```

Using that you can type the `args` argument as:

```
function fireMiddleware<EventName extends keyof MiddlewareEvent>(
    eventId: keyof MiddlewareEvent,
    args: Parameters<MiddlewareEvent[EventName]>
) {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3&ssl=20&ssc=66&pln=20&pc=1#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)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn`t know about type inference and the Parameter keyword. I learned something new today!

Comment: Happy to help! :)